# Why am i getting an empty array in my image? Fetching data from strapi

Tags: reactjs, axios, strapi

Below are snippets of my code. Im mapping my data to rename item.image.url but I am getting and undefined value on my image.

```
export function flattenProducts(data) {
  return data.map((item) => {
    let image = item.image.url
    return { ...item, image };
  });
}
React.useEffect(() => {
 
    axios.get(`${url}/products`).then((response) => {
      
      const products = flattenProducts(response.data);
      console.log(products);
    });
}, []);
```

Please see the images below. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

[image: data from strapi]

[image: Console log result]

[image: Images not rendering]

Answer (score 3):

Your question actually answers itself. You try to map Strapi thinks that your `image` is an array (of images or other data). When you try to map `item.image.url` it is not actually right. Even if you have one item in the array, you can not refer it without pointing out the index of the array element. For example it would work if you write `item.image[0].url` instead of `item.image.url` inside `flattenProducts` function, as @[viet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63757311/4307534) pointed out. Try:

```js
export function flattenProducts(data) {
  return data.map((item) => {
    let image = item.image[0].url
    return { ...item, image };
  });
}
```

The best solution for the problem would be changing the content type of your image element inside Strapi Admin Panel.

Answer (score 1):

Following your data return. The item.image is an array.
So, `let image = item.image[0]?.url` should work.